# WordPress не выводятся посты

Tags: wordpress

Есть страница блог, и тут я пытаюсь вывести посты, но когда я пишу этот цикл `if ( have_posts() ) : query_post...` то страница пустая, в неё вообще ничего не грузится, страницу я называю page-blog.php, в чём может быть проблема? В админке я захожу на страницу Блог переключаю на шаблон Blog(так как мы в верху page-blog.php Дали название шаблона Blog

page-blog.php

```
    <?php
/* Template Name: Blog */
get_header(); ?>
        <article>
            <section class="mblog">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="mblog__wrapper">
                        <?php
                            if ( have_posts() ) : query_posts('cat=6');
                            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="mblog__col">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="mblog__post-item">
                                        <div class="mblog__post-img-wp js-bg-img">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mblog__post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                       <div class="mblog__post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            <? endwhile;
                            endif;
                        wp_reset_query();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Что значит *"страницу я называю page-blog.php"*? Где вы её так называете?

Comment: Вот тут https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/ развёрнуто объясняют, почему не следует использовать `query_posts` никогда.

Comment: page-blog.php в корне проэкта где лежат все файлы мои, Index.php, function.php, header.php и этот, я думал что созданые мной страницы нужно вставлять page-...

Comment: можете подсказать какой тогда будет здесь цикл тогда, как правильно записать

Comment: Страницы вы создаёте в админке wordpress и там же для страниц можете использовать разные шаблоны оформления. Свои шаблоны для страниц нужно помещать в директорию текущей темы.

Comment: @DimaVleskov https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B9_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B Ида - почитай про опасность `query_posts`

Comment: а какой должен быть цикл правильный для вывода постов в моём случаи? тоесть я как понял мне нужно переименовать страницу в category-blog.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

правильно было использовать другой цикл а именно new WP_Query

```
<?php
/* Template Name: blog */
get_header(); ?>
<article>
    <section class="mblog">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mblog__wrapper">
                <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=6' ); ?>
                <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="mblog__col">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="mblog__post-item">
                            <div class="mblog__post-img-wp js-bg-img">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mblog__post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                            <div class="mblog__post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                            <div class="mblog__post-footer">
                                <div class="mblog__post-date"><?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?></div>
                                <div class="mblog__post-comment">
                                    <svg class="mblog__post-comment-icon">
                                        <use xlink:href="#comment"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    <span class="mblog__post-comment-number">10</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mblog__post-overlay">
                                <span class="mblog__post-btn">Read Article</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                else : ?>
                    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</article>
<?php
get_footer(); ?>
```